# SQL time intervals from seperate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have 2 different tables called observations and intervals.

observations:

```
id, type, start
----------
1 classroom 2017-06-07 16:18:40
2 classroom 2017-06-01 15:12:00
----------
```

intervals:

```
id, observation id, number, task, time
----------
1 1 1 1 2017-06-07 16:18:48
2 1 2 0 2017-06-07 16:18:55
3 1 3 1 2017-06-07 16:19:00
4 2 1 3 2017-06-01 15:12:10
5 2 2 1 2017-06-01 15:12:15
----------
```

I want a view that will display:

observation_id

```
time_on_task (total time in seconds where task = 1)
----------
1 13
2 5
----------
```

So I must first check to see if the first observation has task = 1, if it is I must record the difference between the current interval and the start from the observations table, then add that to the total time. From there on after if the task = 1, I just add the time difference from the current interval and previous interval.

I know I can use TIMESTAMPDIFF() or TIMEDIFF() to get the difference in dates.

I believe I will have to use an inner join but do not know the best way to approach this query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to join ? I think this can  done using one table only as per your expected output. And your time to task for 1 should be 12 not 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your expected output by using this query.

```
select observation_id, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(max(time),min(time)))
from your_table
group by observation_id
```

Edited as per comment added:

```
set @preObservationid= 0; 
set @row_number= 0;
set @preTime = '';
select observation_id , 
sum(if(rownumber = 1, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time,start)) ,TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time,pretime))))
from 
( select observation_id, task, rownumber, time, start ,pretime
from ( select observation_id, task, time, start, @preTime as pretime, @preTime:= time,
if(@preObservationid = observation_id, @row_number:= @row_number + 1, @row_number:= 1) as rownumber ,

@preObservationid := observation_id 
from observations o join intervals i on o.id = i.observation_id
order by observation_id,time ) innertable
where task = 1 ) final
group by observation_id
```

I hope this will help you. Let me explain logic.

1. Add rownumber in order to find first record as you said if first
   record has task = 1 then we have to use start as time.
2. Add one more column pretime which is nothing but giving one extra
   column with previous date this is used for your seconnd case. if it
   is task = 1 but not first record.
3. Now you have all data to calculate your time.
4. you can debug at your own by removing each subquery and run it.
5. There is no need of final subquery you can remove it.

Comment: This only gives me the total time from observation 1. I need the total time from observation 1 where task = 1. Those intervals would be:

Comment: This only gives me the total time from observation 1. I need the total time from observation 1 where task = 1. Those intervals would be: 16:18:40 - 16:18:48, 16:18:55 - 16:19:00. This adds up to 13 seconds. The time in the intervals table is the end time for each task. My biggest trouble is getting the initial start time from the observation table if the first interval (which is indicated by the "number" variable) has task = 1. So in this case I would need the timediff between 16:18:40 and 16:18:48 added to the total. 16:18:40 is the initial start time for the first observation.

Comment: @AustinHardesty I have updated answer let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and it should probably work but I am getting this on phpmyadmin:       #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @preObservationid= 0; set @row_number= 0; set @preTime = ''; select obse' at line 6

Comment: @AustinHardesty, I tested this for you in phpmyadmin. MySQL version 5.6 and it is working without any error.